# Find specific child element and change class name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to toggle a class name in a span inside a button. I'm using native javaScript.

How can I find the child element of my button and toggle a class?

I would like to toggle `glyphicon-volume-up` and `glyphicon-volume-off` in the `<span>`.

This is what I have been trying:

```
 function changeButtonType(btn, value) {
   btn.title = value;
   btn.className = value;
   btn.setAttribute("aria-label", value);
   var span = document.getElementById(btn).children;
   //span[1].className = value;
   //var glyph = '<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-'+value+'"></span>';
   //span.innerHTML = glyph;
   //el.appendChild(span);
 }
```

Html:

```
<button type="button" id="mute-button" class="mute" title="Unmute" onclick="toggleMute();">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

See [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kcxhso0n/1/).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`Element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to retrieve the span and then remove/add classes to it using its [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property.

```
var span = btn.querySelector('.glyphicon');
span.classList.remove('glyphicon-volume-off', 'glyphicon-volume-up');
span.classList.add('glyphicon-' + value);
```

Working demo (see mute button below the video):

```js
var mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('video');
var muteBtn = document.getElementById('mute-button');

function changeButtonType(btn, value) {
  btn.title = value;
  btn.className = value;
  btn.setAttribute("aria-label", value);

  var span = btn.querySelector('.glyphicon');
  span.classList.remove('glyphicon-volume-off', 'glyphicon-volume-up');
  span.classList.add('glyphicon-' + value);
}

function toggleMute() {
  if (mediaPlayer.muted) {
    // Change the cutton to be a mute button
    changeButtonType(muteBtn, 'volume-off');
    // Unmute the media player
    mediaPlayer.muted = false;
  } else {
    // Change the button to be an unmute button
    changeButtonType(muteBtn, 'volume-up');
    // Mute the media player
    mediaPlayer.muted = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<video id="video" autoplay muted>
<source src="https://addpipe.com/sample_vid/short.mp4" />
</video>
<button type="button" id="mute-button" class="mute" title="Unmute" onclick="toggleMute();">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up" aria-hidden="true">MUTE</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks you. I made it work with your code. I wonder why my question got downvoted, though...

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array of classes (`classes`) to toggle between, here the classes are your two glyph-icons:

```
const classes = ["glyphicon-volume-off", "glyphicon-volume-up"];
```

Using this code:

```
const index_b = span.classList.contains(classes[0]);
span.classList.remove(classes[+!index_b]);
span.classList.add(classes[+index_b]);
```

You can toggle between the two glyph-icons defined in the array when you click your button. Also, I suggest either moving your code to the bottom of your `<body>` tags (this can be done in your fiddle settings) or adding an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` so that your code knows how to reference the elements within it.

See working example below:

```js
var mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('video');
var muteBtn = document.getElementById('mute-button');


const classes = ["glyphicon-volume-off", "glyphicon-volume-up"];

function changeButtonType(btn, value) {
  btn.title = value;
  btn.className = value;
  btn.setAttribute("aria-label", value);
  var span = document.getElementById(btn.id).children[0];

  const index_b = span.classList.contains(classes[0]);
  span.classList.remove(classes[+!index_b]);
  span.classList.add(classes[+index_b]);
}

function toggleMute() {
  if (mediaPlayer.muted) {
    // Change the cutton to be a mute button
    changeButtonType(muteBtn, 'volume-off');
    // Unmute the media player
    mediaPlayer.muted = false;
  } else {
    // Change the button to be an unmute button
    changeButtonType(muteBtn, 'volume-up');
    // Mute the media player
    mediaPlayer.muted = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<video id="video" autoplay muted>
<source src="https://addpipe.com/sample_vid/short.mp4" />
</video>
<button type="button" id="mute-button" class="mute" title="Unmute" onclick="toggleMute();">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

See [js fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/clapynick/7y60azrp/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Create one more button for unmute and keep its style as `display:none` and then in toggle function change the visibility accordingly,

```
var mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('video');
 var muteBtn = document.getElementById('mute-button');
 var unmuteBtn = document.getElementById('unmute-button');


 function toggleMute() {
   if (mediaPlayer.muted) {
     // Change the button to be a mute button
     unmuteBtn.style.display='block';
     muteBtn.style.display='none';
     // Unmute the media player
     mediaPlayer.muted = false;
   } else {
     // Change the button to be an unmute button
     muteBtn.style.display='block';
     unmuteBtn.style.display='none';
     // Mute the media player
     mediaPlayer.muted = true;
   }
 }
```

See [Js fiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/fuqvLt26/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm normally in favor of separate js solutions, without onevent handlers, but if this is all you want (toggle on/off), then this'll do:

```
<video id="video" autoplay muted>
<source src="https://addpipe.com/sample_vid/short.mp4" />
</video>
<button type="button" id="mute-button" class="mute" title="Unmute" onclick="var e = this.firstElementChild; e.className = e.matches('[class*=up]') ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/dmxa79sh/);